# How do I gtest that code did not call exit()

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I'd like to test this function with Google Test:

```
foo() {
    if(some_grave_error)
        exit(1);
    // do something
}
```

I want my test to fail if `foo` calls `std::exit()`. How do I do this? It is sort of inverse to what **EXPECT_EXIT** does?

Comment: Can't you just `EXPECT_EXIT` with exit code 0?

Comment: Not too familiar with gtest, but what happens if you don't have any check? If `foo` calls `exit`, does the test fail automatically? Or does it actually exit? If `foo` doesn't call `exit` then the test will succeed as you don't check for anything.

Comment: To be able to test this properly it is best to write code which is testable.
Basically you should write code where any external function calls could be mocked. Alternative is to use "die test" [here it is documented](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#death-tests).

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48021953/4117728

Comment: What I don't understand is that if you want to test f, it means that you expect (positive) side effect of calling this function. Either it return something that could be tested again , or it has a side effect that hopefully should be tested too.  That is what you should test first (comparing obtained values vs expected values => focusing of behavior, not on known algorithm). Then you could make a death test for the `negative` side effect ( negative case)   of exit(1)  as suggested by @MarekR with a death test.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should make `foo()` testable:

```
using fexit_callback = void(*)(int);
void foo(fexit_callback exit = &std::exit)
{
    if(some_condition)
        exit(1);
}
```

And magically, all your troubles disappear:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>

using fexit_callback = void(*)(int);
void foo(fexit_callback exit = &std::exit)
{
    if(true)
        exit(1);
}

namespace mockup
{
    int result = 0;
    void exit(int r) { result = r; }
}

int main()
{
    foo(mockup::exit);
    assert(mockup::result == 1);
}
```

Comment: This won't work though, if `foo()` calls `std::exit` directly or a function called by `foo` (possibly in a library that you can't modify), calls `std::exit`.

Comment: @zett42 I cannot make sense of what you've written. But it works: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1229a92311dea067

Comment: In this contrived example it works. My point is that you don't control all the code you call. Third-party code called by `foo()` may call `std::exit`, which your mockup won't detect.

Comment: @YSC: The point i'm reading in his comment is that if the test is to fail when `std::exit` is called, then all the code has to do to defeat your test is to call `std::exit` rather than your callback -- and any code you didn't write that needs to exit, is going to do just that. Basically the test is unreliable if `foo` calls any code outside of your direct control.

Comment: I get it, and I agree. There is no panacea I fear.